# SSRS Tab Labels in Excel

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Good AFternoon,

I am using a Matrix in SSRS and have it grouped by Regions.  I have set my page names equal to Region Value and have page Breaks at the start of each group.

For some reason when I export to Excel it seems as if the first group is skipped in the naming.

For example:
Sheet 1 Contains the data for Northeast Region
Sheet 2 Contains data for Southeast Region
Sheet 3 Contains data for Midwest Region

When Exporting the Excel the tab names are:
Sheet 1: Southeast
Sheet 2: Southeast(2)
Sheet 3: Midwest

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: set page break *between* each group rather than at the start

Comment: Just tried that again and still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: You need to set the page name as dynamic value not static value . see more detailed information at [Export SQL Server Reporting Services Report Data into Multiple Excel Worksheets](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3527/export-sql-server-reporting-services-report-data-into-multiple-excel-worksheets/)